# Pythagorean closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

UIm reading the book *Galois Theory* by Ian Stewart ($4$th Edition).
Here the author defines the Pythagorean closure as follows:

> **Definition.** The Pythagorean closure $\mathbb{Q}^{PY}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the smallest subfield $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ with the property $z \in K \Rightarrow \pm\sqrt{z} \in K$.

A few pages later he says without further explanation:

> Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}^{PY} $. Then by definition there is a tower:
> $\mathbb{Q} =L_0 \subseteq L_1 \subseteq\dots\subseteq L_n \supseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ such that  $[L_{j+1} : L_j] = 2$ for all $j$.

I understand that each quadratic adjunction has degree $2$. But for me it is not obvious why the existence of such tower follows from the definition. How can it be constructed?

Comment: The field consisting of the union of all such towers is closed under taking square roots.

Comment: What means the union of towers? Why is this a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: appending a square root to a field $K$, as in $K(\sqrt{a})$ for $a \in K$, makes a Galois extension of degree $2$.

**Theorem** The pythagorean closure $\mathbb{Q}^{PY}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is equal to the union of all subfields $L \subset \mathbb{C}$ for which there is a filtration $L_0 \subset L_1 \subset \cdots \subset L_n = L$ where each consecutive extension of degree $2$.

On the one hand, it must include these extensions, being closed under square roots and field operations. On the other hand, this construction forms a field. For two $L_0 \subset L_1 \subset \cdots \subset L_n = L$ and $M_0 \subset M_1 \subset \cdots \subset M_n = M$, we can make $L_0 \subset L_1 \subset \cdots \subset L_n \subset L_n M_0 \subset L_n M_1 \subset \cdots \subset L_n M_n$, and each will have degree $1$ or $2$.

Now an element $\alpha$ in the pythagorean closure is going to be contained in one of these $L$ such that there is a filtration $L_0 \subset L_1 \subset \cdots \subset L_n = L$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is also contained in $L$.

Comment: I think the proof is correct - with one exception. I do not see why the product of fields is itself a field (e.g. when $a_1 b_1 \in AB$ and $a_2 b_2 \in AB$ why should $a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 \in AB$?.

Comment: I think we can fix the proof: For the two towers $L_0  \subset L_0(\alpha_1)  \subset L_0(\alpha_1, \alpha_2) ... \subset L_0(\alpha_1,...\alpha_n)$ and  $M_0  \subset M_0(\beta_1)  \subset M_0(\beta_1, \beta_2) ... \subset M_0(\beta_1,...\beta_m)$ (where each extension is quadratic), we can make the compound extension like this: $L_0  \subset L_0(\alpha_1)  \subset L_0(\alpha_1, \alpha_2) ... \subset L_0(\alpha_1,...\alpha_n) \subset L_0(\alpha_1,...\alpha_n, \beta_1) \subset L_0(\alpha_1,...\alpha_n, \beta_1, ...\beta_m)$, and remove all extensions of degree 1.

Comment: For subfields $L$ and $M$ of a field $K$, $LM$ is the smallest field containing them.

Comment: @KindBubble "On the one hand, it must include these extensions, being closed under square roots and field operations." Could you elaborate a bit on why it is impossible to have a nested fields $L_0 \subset L_1 \subset \cdots \subset L_n = L$, which is closed under square roots and field operations, and also $L \cap \mathbb{Q}^{py}=\emptyset$? Many thanks in advance!